# content classification API for the google cloud?

Tags: text, google-cloud-platform, classification

I am trying to use the google cloud platform to classify text much like what is done with the text classification example in Python SciKit Learn.  Does anyone know if this capability exists?  I've found the NL API, but can't seem to find anything for classification.

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Its now avialable but as beta feature:
https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/classifying-text